# Is it wise to edit the default Google Analytics path exclusions?

Tags: 7, google-analytics

The Google Analytics module has a default configuration under the "Pages" tab: "Add tracking to specific pages". The listed exceptions are:

```
admin
admin/*
batch
node/add*
node/*/*
user/*/*
```

I'm using Webform, which generates confirmation pages like `node/125/done` by default. I could of course create specified paths for each of my webform confirmation pages, but there are many on the site (over 50), so the easier route would just be to remove `node/*/*` from the GA exclusions.

What repercussions might arise from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should mean that pages such as EDIT nodes, will appear and be tracked by google analytics, which could cause false numbers.  You could change the exceptions by removing the

```
node/*/*
```

but including other specifically excluded content, such as

```
node/*/edit.
```

You would want to keep an eye on google analytics to see if other pages are creaping in and then exclude them as you find them.